# can i go back? see version history in visual studio code?

Tags: html, visual-studio-code

I accidentally closed out and now I need to go back and undo a lot. is there any way to see version history to go back a lot and undo many things? I have tried to undo many times and it just stops. on google docs you can see all version history, does anyone have anything I could try to do?

Comment: install an incremental backup, or a versioned save system, but then you might complain about all the versions you have, you can use a version control like `git` and save some versions in the repository

Comment: wait... explain in english please to a new coder

Comment: how do you assume that the undo of VSC is persistent. It should be in one of the later versions and I don't know if it is on by default. Otherwise make regular backups. If your a new coder I don't think your code is very large, just change your current code to what you want